# Angular/Typescript For consuming a json webservice I need create all class returned?

Tags: json, angular, google-maps, typescript, google-api

I wanna consuming this [service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=pt-br):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

I need only two data:

```
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -10.6872332,
           "lng" : -37.4329352
```

But this ws return 11 diferent class. My question is:  **Is necessary to create all this chain class for use only 2 fields?**

At moment my method are stopped in this point.

```
getCoord(city:string): Observable<any>
{
    return this._http.get(this.urlBase+cidade+this.key)
        //.map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I not. For to use only some properties of json, need only create class/path for location of data. In my case, for get Location{lat: number; lng: number;} I create a object/class and some interfaces:

```
interface Location{lat: number; lng: number;}
interface Geometry{location: Location;}
interface Result{geometry: Geometry;}

export class GeocoderResult {
    results: Array<Result>;
    status: string;

    constructor() {
        this.results = new Array<Result>();
    }
}
```

and in .TS file my method work great:

```
key: string = '&key=XXX';
urlBase: string = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=';
city: string = 'yourCityName';

getCoord(city: string): any
{
    return this._http.get<GeocoderResult>(this.urlBase+city+this.key)
    .subscribe(data => {    
        return data.results[0].geometry.location;
        //console.log('geo = ', data.results[0].geometry.location);
    });
}
```